How do you show and hide the keyboard without TextField?
My current code creates a FocusNode that KeyboardListener uses to focus and unfocus when the screen is tapped. That doesn't open the keyboard so I added SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show") and SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.hide"), but these are not working on iOS simulation or real iOS device.
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyClass({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyClass> createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
late FocusNode _focusNode;

KeyEventResult keyEventHandler(KeyEvent event) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("handle key: ${event.logicalKey}");
  }
  return KeyEventResult.handled;
}

@override
void initState() {
  _focusNode = new FocusNode(
    debugLabel: "wordlet",
  );
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _focusNode.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return KeyboardListener(
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    onKeyEvent: keyEventHandler,
    autofocus: true,
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
          _focusNode.unfocus();
          SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.hide");
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("unfocus");
          }
        } else {
          _focusNode.requestFocus();
          SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("focus requested");
          }
        }
      }, // onTap
    ), // GestureDetector
  ), // KeyboardListener
} // build
} // _MyClassState

Flutter doctor output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.3)
[✓] Connected device (6 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

iOS Simulator iPhone 15, iOS 17.5
I tried to open the keyboard by tapping the screen. I receive the debug print "focus requested" and "unfocus" but no keyboard open.
flutter: unfocus
flutter: focus requested

I also confirmed that text input is being read in when using iOS simulator and typing on my laptop keyboard.
flutter: handle key: LogicalKeyboardKey#12bb1(keyId: "0x00000061", keyLabel: "A", debugName: "Key A")
flutter: handle key: LogicalKeyboardKey#1e0f5(keyId: "0x00000065", keyLabel: "E", debugName: "Key E")
flutter: handle key: LogicalKeyboardKey#34b7d(keyId: "0x0000006d", keyLabel: "M", debugName: "Key M")
flutter: handle key: LogicalKeyboardKey#12bb1(keyId: "0x00000061", keyLabel: "A", debugName: "Key A")


In Flutter, you can programmatically show and hide the keyboard even without relying on a TextField by using the FocusNode and FocusScope classes. Here's how you can achieve it:
Showing the Keyboard
To show the keyboard, you need to attach a FocusNode to a FocusScope and request focus. For this to work, there should be a widget capable of receiving input (e.g., EditableText).
Hiding the Keyboard
To hide the keyboard, you can unfocus the FocusNode by using FocusScope.of(context).unfocus().
E.g
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: KeyboardExample(),
    );
  }
}

class KeyboardExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KeyboardExampleState createState() => _KeyboardExampleState();
}

class _KeyboardExampleState extends State<KeyboardExample> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  void _showKeyboard() {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
  }

  void _hideKeyboard() {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Keyboard Control Example")),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          EditableText(
            controller: TextEditingController(),
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            backgroundCursorColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _showKeyboard,
            child: Text("Show Keyboard"),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _hideKeyboard,
            child: Text("Hide Keyboard"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Explanation

EditableText: This widget is used to render text that can accept
input. It's minimal but necessary to interact with the keyboard.
FocusNode: Used to manage focus on widgets. Attaching a FocusNode to
a widget allows it to gain focus programmatically.
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus: Requests focus for a specific
FocusNode, which will bring up the keyboard.
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(): Removes focus from the current
FocusNode, effectively hiding the keyboard.

Notes

The keyboard won't show up unless there is a focusable widget like
EditableText or TextField.
If you only want to control the keyboard visibility without user
interaction, you still need to attach it to some focusable widget.

